# How do I make a button that resorts data on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a page that lists all the events in my database of events. I want to create a button that says "my events" that when pressed reloads the page but then only displays events that belong to the current_user. I tried doing something like this:

```
<%= button_to "My Events", events_path(:my_events => true) %>
```

and then I was going to add an if statement to the events_controller index that filters @events if my_events is true. However, this button just creates a new event for some reason.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do what you want:
add an action find_my_events in your events controller:
`find_my_events`
`@events = current_user.events(:all)`
`render :action => 'index'` 
 
`end`

Now, in your view, create a form_tag and associate it with find_my_events:
(you can either create a new route in your routes.rb or use :controller => 'events', :action => 'find_my_events', i prefer the former)
Add a submit_tag to your form.

So, now when you submit the form, the page refreshes and fetches events for the current user.

You can also submit a form to your index action with a boolean hidden field.  Now in your index action check if that boolean field is set to true, if yes, display events for the current_user or all events otherwise.

Comment: where would that helper go? also, how will it know which page to load up when the helper is called?

Comment: This didn't work. I got this error:
undefined local variable or method `find_my_events_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001032efd98>:0x000001032e35c0>

Comment: still nothing. I created the action in my events controller like you said. Then I put the button you showed me above in the index.html.erb event view. This is the error I got: undefined local variable or method `find_my_events' for #<#<Class:0x00000105145b30>:0x00000105143d80>

Comment: my bad! i modified my solution above